How to install mkl library on Ubuntu 24.04?
While installing numpy==1.19.5 in a python environment with python 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 24.04, I am unable to install numpy because of missing MKL library and gcc compilation error.
how to resolve this?
P.S I need this python version to support my system.

MKL library packages should be available from the multiverse repository e.g. intel-mkl. However AFAIK numpy uses OpenBLAS rather then MKL by default. If you want specific help you will need to [edit] your question with more details about your build process and the actual compilation error(s).

non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
NOT AVAILABLE

error: inlining failed in call to ‘always_inline’ ‘_mm512_mask_storeu_ps’: target specific option mismatch
6373 | _mm512_mask_storeu_ps (void *__P, __mmask16 __U, __m512 __A)
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
numpy/core/src/umath/simd.inc.src:2891:9: note: called from here
2891 |         mm512_mask_storeu@vsuffix@(op, load_mask, out);
|         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include/avx512fintrin.h:12607:1: error: inlining failed in call to ‘always_inline’ ‘_mm512_add_ps’: target specific option mismatch

error: Command "gcc -g -Og -Wall -mno-avx512f -fPIC -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -

Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/local/include/python3.6dm -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6-pydebug/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6-pydebug/build/src.linux-x86_64-

3.6/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.o.d -std=c99" failed with exit status 1
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy

Please [edit] all that information into your question - it is very hard to read in comments
